# What is the name of this Mac OS X control?

Tags: cocoa, macos, controls

Does this control have a name? Or is it just a bunch of simple controls merged together? If so, what controls are they?

http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/3002/picture2xrb.png

Comment: My reputation isn't high enough to add tags for you. You should probably tag this with 'cocoa'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like an `NSTableView` with an a custom cell type and no column header. Have a look at the documentation for `NSTableView`'s `tableView:dataCellForTableColumn:row:`. For columns which have the same type for all rows you may also set the cell class in interface builder.

I doubt the search box is part of the same control.

You could open the Application's Nib file to see what is in there. Look inside the application bundle. If the application is called `Example` then you should be able to find the Nib at `Example.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/MainMenu.nib`.

Comment: Good answer, although since we're talking about OS X, forward slashes are what you want to use here.

Comment: Quite right. I've fixed it. I'm actually a long term Mac user but if I'm typing on a Windows machine I automatically change to backslashes.

Answer (score 4):

The best tool for investigating this is [fscript](http://www.fscript.org), specifically FScriptAnywhere which will let you determine the class and much other information about any visual element of any Cocoa program (and do a lot of other interesting things with Cocoa programs).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what toholio said, an easy way to get the look and feel of the bottom button bar is with [BWToolkit](http://www.brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/).